# Having difficulty proving that the set of nth degree monic polynomials that split on R is closed in Rn(X) with supremum norm using topological methods

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $\Bbb R_n[X]$ be the metric space of $n$-th degree polynomials with real coefficients and polynomial height (supremum norm) as norm. Then, let $E_n$ be the subset of all monic polynomials in $\Bbb R_n[X]$ that split over $\Bbb R$. Show that $E_n$ is closed in $\Bbb R_n[X]$. I have no idea how to progress. Just giving a hint on how to solve to me would be fine.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of the norm?

Comment: the maximum of the modulus of the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: So $\| a_n x^n + \ldots a_1 x +  a_0\|  =\max_{i=0}^n |a_i|$?

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Comment: This might be helpful: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Lagrange's_and_Cauchy's_bounds